# How can I have Ubuntu 21.10 automatically lock the screen after a certain time period?

Tags: lock-screen

Currently my screen stays unlocked and on permanently if I stop using my system.

Is there a way I can have the screen automatically lock?

Comment: What type of locking are you looking for?  A certain amount of time for the system being idle like not touching the mouse or keyboard?  Super+L for instant lock?  A proximity lock like if you walk away from your system to a certain distance it will automatically lock like what [Blueproximity](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/blueproximity.1.html) can do?  Screensavers like XScreensaver can lock your screen after a certain amount of time.  A little more details can really help us help you!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One can set the screen to automatically lock in Settings - Screen Lock. Switch on "Automatic Screen Lock", then tweak the timing using the "Automatic Screen Lock Delay".

[image]
"Screen turns off" means that the screen will be locked, as soon as it is turned off according to the settings under "Power". Alternatively, you can specify periods independent on the settings for screen blanking.